# Duplicated PHP condition content for SEO

Tags: php, seo, responsive-design

for responsive web design purposes I'd like to use PHP conditions like in this pseudo code :

```
if(small_screen_resolution){
   <small div>
     My content
   </small div>
else{
   <div>
     My content
   </div> 
 }
```

I was just wondering how would Google bot consider "My content" since it appears two times in my code, does Google consider it like a duplicated content (which isn't good for SEO) or not ?

Thanks !

Comment: It shouldn't be an issue like John states, but you can probably better use responsive CSS for stuff like that

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Google doesn't see your server side code. They only see the content your code produces. So this isn't an issue.

Answer (score 1):

Your result html code  will be one of the `<small div>` or `<div>`, and this is whatever Google sense it, not you server side PHP code. so it's not an issue.